# Grab an exact image at exact time in FFMpeg video?

Tags: java, ffmpeg, frame-grab

I am trying to build a project in java that uses this library: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv

I want to use the FFmpegFrameGrabber to get an exact frame of a video, but the only methods I see are `FFmpegFrameGrabber.grab()`.  How does this know what frame to extract when it does not accept an input?  I feel like there should be a time in milliseconds or a frame number to specify, not sure though.

If you have any ideas I'd love your input.